# Query to add to each element of an array a field from another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of chat and user. I want to get a messages array from the chat collection, slice out some items and add a senderName field to each item. The value of senderName can be found using $lookup by DBRef sender. Here is what I did:

```
db.chat.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // Find chat
      "_id": ObjectId("65d72b8d38e0970f7140015a")
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      // Slice out some messages
      "messages": {
        "$slice": [
          "$messages",
          0,
          4
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      // Add field senderId with value of sender.$id converted to ObjectId
      "messages": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$messages",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "senderId": {
                  "$toObjectId": "$$this.sender.$id"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      // Get all senders
      "from": "user",
      "let": {
        "senderIds": "$messages.senderId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$_id",
                "$$senderIds"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            // Project only senderName
            "senderName": "$userDetails.displayedName",
            "senderId": "$_id",
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "sendersData"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "messages": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$messages",
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$m",
              {
                "$first": {
                  // Find sender in sendersData
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$sendersData",
                    "as": "f",
                    "cond": {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$f.senderId",
                        "$$m.senderId"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "messages.senderId"
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/pT8RtpNIqNJ

Any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "improve" ? What is the specific issue you are facing and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: @ray I'm new to mongodb, so I'd like a more experienced programmer to check this query. Maybe it can be made more readable, or more performant, or different approach instead of $map could be used.I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, because the task of adding 1 field from another collection stretches over 100+ lines and almost 1000 characters

Comment: I am sorry but stackoverflow is a site about asking and answering specific programming questions, rather than doing code review. The question now looks opinion-based as it lacks a [mre] and should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified a bit to 4 simple steps. I don't see an efficient way to do it with less. You can use the concept of `population`, but it should be less efficient.

```
db.chat.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("65d72b8d38e0970f7140015a")}},
  {"$project": {"messages": {"$slice": ["$messages", 0, 4]}}},
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "let": {"senderIds": "$messages.sender.$id"},
      "pipeline": [
        {"$match": {"$expr": {"$in": [{"$toString": "$_id"}, "$$senderIds"]}}},
        {"$project": {
           "senderName": "$userDetails.displayedName",
            "id": {"$toString": "$_id"},
            "_id": 0
        }}
      ],
      "as": "sendersData"
  }},
  {"$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "sendersData": "$$REMOVE",
      "messages": {"$map": {
          "input": "$messages",
          "in": {"$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {"senderName": {
                  "$getField": {
                    "input": {"$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$sendersData",
                        {"$indexOfArray": ["$sendersData.id", "$$this.sender.$id"]}
                    ]},
                    "field": "senderName"
                  }
              }}
          ]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W6URMv0p6-k)

It could be even [shorter](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-KnxP3Pb3ms), when using simple `_id` without `ref`: